# Java wildfly java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am developing javaee maven web project using wildfly server and when I start master node everything runs with no error, but when I start slave node I get error on slave node server and master node server.

Master node server error:

```
17:28:07,472 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-8) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component NodesManagementBean for method public abstract void agents.clustering.NodesManagementLocal.registerNodes(java.util.List) throws agents.clustering.exception.AliasExistsException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: WFLYEJB0457: Unexpected Error
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:153)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:256)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:329)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
at agents.clustering.NodesManagementLocal$$$view27.registerNodes(Unknown Source)
at agents.clustering.service.http.NodesREST.addNodes(NodesREST.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
at agents.clustering.service.http.NodesEndpointREST$$$view12.addNodes(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:130)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: agents/environment/agents/service/http/AgentsRequester
at agents.clustering.NodesManagementBean.getAgentClasses(NodesManagementBean.java:97)
at agents.clustering.NodesManagementBean.registerNodes(NodesManagementBean.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
... 157 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: agents.environment.agents.service.http.AgentsRequester from [Module "deployment.agents.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
... 188 more
```

Slave node error:

```
17:28:07,487 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101) Exception in thread "Thread-101" javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
17:28:07,488 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101)    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:209)
17:28:07,488 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101)    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:174)
17:28:07,488 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101)    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:60)
17:28:07,488 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101)    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:104)
17:28:07,488 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101)    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
17:28:07,488 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.addNodes(Unknown Source)
17:28:07,488 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101)    at agents.clustering.service.http.NodesRequester.addNodes(NodesRequester.java:21)
17:28:07,488 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101)    at agents.clustering.startup.StartupBean.lambda$0(StartupBean.java:90)
17:28:07,488 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-101)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I was tring to find answer on similar question but nothing worked for me.

Comment: This usually means the application does not come bundled with the dependency providing the class that's missing.

Comment: have you tried to do a `mvn clean package` ?

Comment: @MaQuiNa1995 I run mvn clean and mvn install and error is still the same

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens AgentsRequester is my class, every other class from same and other packages are loaded properly except this one, how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle for dependencys management ?